# Roles on Snowflake - I do not want to see all databases

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I want to create a role on snowflake limited only to one database and one schema and give there a read access on all tables.

I create a role, grant:
grant usage on database1,
grant usage on database1.schema1,
grat select on all tables in database1.schema1,
and I grant usage and operate on one warehouse1.

However, additionally to this I am seeing also other databases and other schemas with this role, despite no grants were added, also there is additional warehouse to warehouse1.

How I can limit access with this role and not see something that appear as default
'databases' even for roles with no grants?
Regards
P

Comment: Which objects can you see with this role? Ones that are created by default by Snowflake or ones that your company has created?

Comment: @NickW Ones that were created by company. Those are not default Snowflake objects, but databases and warehouses created by developers, and I want a role that will be able to see only one schema in one of databases, not seeing the rest

Comment: @PiotrCiepiela Is the role you are using the same you defined `SELECT CURRENT_ROLE(), CURRENT_SECONDARY_ROLES()` and `SHOW GRANTS TO ROLE <role_name>` . Does it contain anything more than you have stated in the question?

Comment: Ok - so you need to look at the privileges assigned to those objects and work out how they are also being assigned to your user. This is not something someone without access to your Snowflake account can help with - unless you are asking how to determine those privileges?

Comment: @LukaszSzozda no, the current role is my role, in seconary role field there is only: {"roles":"","value":""} ,  in grants there is only sage on database and schema that I wanted to have, but still seeing the other

Comment: Have the objects you can see been assigned to the PUBLIC role?

Comment: @NickW , yes you are right. I see that IT was not a good practice in that case. Is there maybe a chance to create users without public role, but with custom role only?

Comment: No - the purpose of the PUBLIC role is to give everyone access to an object. If that’s it what you want then don’t use the PUBLIC role

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to find out what the role can and cannot do.

Check the which users and/or roles are granted the privilege of the role:
show grants of role ;

Then check what privileges were given to the role:
show grants to role ;

All the users are granted the PUBLIC role. Hence, never grant any privileges to the PUBLIC role, as this simply means giving the whole world access to a database, schema and tables/views etc.